# How to evaluate the importance of input in LSTM?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm

I want to evaluate the importance of input in LSTM network to rank the The importance of input. Is there any methods or literature about this research?

Comment: What do you mean by "the importance of input"? Do you want to do some feature important analysis similar to what can be done e.g. with random forests?

Comment: I want to evaluate the variables importance of LSTM in order to rank the input variables which  makes more contributions to the output of LSTM

Comment: @JiYuZhang Have you found an answer to this question?